# How to get schema of our table without filling its DataTable before calling NewRow method?

Tags: ado.net, newrow

I know that I should have schema of a table before calling NewRow method in order to add a new row to a DataTable....

But as you know, having the schema of a table means filling its DataTable by records from DB. This means connecting to DB and fetch records.

Is there any way to have schema without performing a select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET FMTONLY ON

Select * From dbo.Users
```

The above query retrieves table schema only.